# AngularJS em projeto "Grande"

Tags: angularjs, microsserviços

Leio pela literatura que AngularJS é feito para *single page*.

E se eu usar o mesmo para uma aplicação maior, com vária telas. Quais seriam os impactos negativos de usar o AngularJS? E se eu quisesse que esses impactos não fossem gerados, mas continuar usando o AngularJS, eu poderia pensar numa arquitetura de microservices?

Comment: *Single Page Application* não é uma aplicação que só tem uma página. Basicamente, uma SPA é uma aplicação que é desenvolvida mais do lado cliente do que do servidor. Isto é, ao invés de gerar os HTML's do lado do servidor e trafegá-los para entregar ao cliente, se usa uma abordagem onde se trafegam principalmente dados e o cliente é responsável pelas modificações no HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> AngularJs é feito para single page, certo?

Sim, Angular é um framework para aplicações de página única - o que significa que seu modelo operacional previne *reloads* completos (como numa navegação para outra página, por exemplo, onde o browser descarta a página atual e carrega todos os recursos indicados na nova página).

> E se eu usar o mesmo para uma aplicação maior, com vária telas. Quais seriam os impactos negativos de usar o AngularJS?

Nenhum - ou melhor, depende do modelo de implementação. Da mesma maneira como soluções sub-otimizadas em HTML tradicional existem (por exemplo usando vários IFRAMEs), uma solução Angular também pode ser mal-desenhada.

O mecanismo equivalente, no mundo Angular, ao fluxo de navegação entre páginas/módulos é conhecido como [rotas](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp).

> E se eu quisesse que esses impactos não fossem gerados, mas continuar usando o AngularJS, eu poderia pensar numa arquitetura de microservices?

Os dois não são relacionados. Os problemas mais comuns em implementações Angular tem a ver com fluxo e carga de recursos. *Microservices* tem como foco granularidade.

Comment: Meu herói ***=)***

Comment: @jbueno * *blushes* *

Comment: O único impacto negativo de usar angular em várias páginas é que a indexação no google provavelmente vai cair. Mas se for uma aplicação que não se preocupa tanto com indexação, use e abuse do AngularJS. Ele facilita muito a nossa vida.

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas. Ajudaram bastante. :D